# C++ suppresses a value twice when outputting unordered_map

Tags: visual-c++, c++17

I am 15 years old and not very experienced in C++. I sketched an interpreter in my head and decided to build it, but in my code below, when I output unordered_mapi in the variable creation section, it prints the same variable twice.
Full Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

void printVect(vector<string> inp, char pchar = '\0') {
    for (const string& w : inp) {
        if (pchar != '\0') { cout << w << pchar; }
        else { cout << w; }
    }cout << "\n";
}

tuple<int, int, int> countToken(vector<string> code, long int start = 0, long int end = 0, string token = "") {
    int count = 0;
    long int konum1 = 0, konum2 = 0;
    if (start == 0 && end == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < code.size(); i++) {
            if (code[i] == token) {
                if (konum1 == 0) {
                    konum1 = i;
                }
                else if (konum2 == 0 && konum1 != 0) {
                    konum2 = i;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        return make_tuple(count, konum1, konum2);
    }
    else {
        for (long int startIndex = start; startIndex <= end; startIndex++) {
            if (code[startIndex] == token) {
                if (konum1 == 0) {
                    konum1 = startIndex;
                }
                else if (konum2 == 0 && konum1 != 0) {
                    konum2 = startIndex;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return make_tuple(count, konum1, konum2-1/*konum2'den 1 çıkardım yoksa son tırnağıda veriyordu*/);
}

long int findToken(vector<string> text, long int startIndex, string ftext) {
    for (startIndex+=1; startIndex < text.size(); startIndex++) {
        if (text[startIndex] == ftext) {
            return startIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1; // bulunamazsa döndürülecek
}

long int charTo(vector<string> code, long int startİndex,string character) {
    for (;;) {
        startİndex++;
        if (code[startİndex] != character) {
            return startİndex;
        }
    }
}

string readTwoİndex(vector<string> code, long int start, long int end) {
    string value="";
    for (long int index=start; index<=end; index++) {
        value += code[index];
    }
    return value;
}

vector<string> Parser(string code, string charset) {
    vector<string> parsingCode;
    string guncelCode;
    for (char c : code) {
        bool found = false;
        for (char checkChar : charset) {
            if (checkChar == c) {
                if (!guncelCode.empty()) {
                    parsingCode.push_back(guncelCode);
                }
                parsingCode.push_back(string(1, c));
                guncelCode = "";
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) { guncelCode += c; }
    }
    return parsingCode;
}

string interpreter(vector<string> code) {
    unordered_map<string, string> strVariables;
    unordered_map<string, float> intVariables;
    string errMessage = "NULL";
    for (long int counter = 0; counter < code.size(); counter++) {
        /*Print start*/
        if (code[counter] == "write") {
            long int openParenIndex = findToken(code, counter, "(");
            if (openParenIndex != -1) {
                long int closeParenIndex = findToken(code, openParenIndex, ")");
                tuple<int, int, int> counterTuple = countToken(code, openParenIndex, closeParenIndex, "\"");
                int tokNum, fKonum, sKonum;
                tie(tokNum, fKonum, sKonum) = counterTuple;
                if (tokNum == 2) {// Tırnak, yani string kontrolü
                    if (fKonum + 1 <= sKonum) {
                        for (int writeCount = fKonum + 1; writeCount <= sKonum; writeCount++) {
                            cout << code[writeCount];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else { cerr << "Hata: Parantez not found." << endl; return errMessage; }
        }/*Print end*/
        /*Create Variable Start*/
        if (code[counter] == "var") {
            //printVect(code,'|');
            string varName, varVal;

            long int charEndİndex = charTo(code, counter, " ");
            varName = code[charEndİndex];
            //cout << "Var name --> " << varName << endl;
            counter = charEndİndex;
            charEndİndex = findToken(code, counter, "=");
            //cout << "Equal --> " << code[charEndİndex] << endl;
            counter = charEndİndex;
            tuple<int, int, int> countQuote = countToken(code, charEndİndex, findToken(code, charEndİndex, ";"), "\"");
            if (get<0>(countQuote) == 2) { // Tırnak işareti kontrolü
                charEndİndex = charTo(code, counter, " ") + 1;
                long int endQuoteCheck = findToken(code, charEndİndex, "\"") - 1;
                varVal = readTwoİndex(code, charEndİndex, endQuoteCheck);

                // Değişken varsa güncelliyeceğiz, yoksa yeni bir değişken olarak ekliyoz
                if (strVariables.find(varName) != strVariables.end()) {
                    strVariables[varName] = varVal; // Değişken adı ve değeri güncellendi.
                }
                else {
                    strVariables[varName] = varVal; // Değişken adı ve değeri atandı.
                }
                counter = endQuoteCheck;
                for (const auto& pair : strVariables) {
                    cout << "Degisken adi: " << pair.first << ", Deger: " << pair.second << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        /* Create variable end */
    }
    return errMessage;
}

int main() {
    string code = "var xas= \"hello\";var ze=\"hi00\";var xas=\"naber\";";
    string charset = "=)(\"; ";
    vector<string> output = Parser(code, charset);
    interpreter(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Problematic Code section :

```
    /*Create Variable Start*/
    if (code[counter] == "var") {
        //printVect(code,'|');
        string varName, varVal;

        long int charEndİndex = charTo(code, counter, " ");
        varName = code[charEndİndex];
        //cout << "Var name --> " << varName << endl;
        counter = charEndİndex;
        charEndİndex = findToken(code, counter, "=");
        //cout << "Equal --> " << code[charEndİndex] << endl;
        counter = charEndİndex;
        tuple<int, int, int> countQuote = countToken(code, charEndİndex, findToken(code, charEndİndex, ";"), "\"");
        if (get<0>(countQuote) == 2) { // Tırnak işareti kontrolü
            charEndİndex = charTo(code, counter, " ") + 1;
            long int endQuoteCheck = findToken(code, charEndİndex, "\"") - 1;
            varVal = readTwoİndex(code, charEndİndex, endQuoteCheck);

            // Değişken varsa güncelliyeceğiz, yoksa yeni bir değişken olarak ekliyoz
            if (strVariables.find(varName) != strVariables.end()) {
                strVariables[varName] = varVal; // Değişken adı ve değeri güncellendi.
            }
            else {
                strVariables[varName] = varVal; // Değişken adı ve değeri atandı.
            }
            counter = endQuoteCheck;
            for (const auto& pair : strVariables) {
                cout << "Degisken adi: " << pair.first << ", Deger: " << pair.second << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    /* Create variable end */
```

How can I solve this problem? I really apologise if I have given incomplete details in the subject. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the incorrect output and the expected output? Can you narrow this down to focus on only the issue you're having? I'm unsure what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Every time the program processes a variable assignment, it prints *all* variables encountered so far, not just the one assigned most recently. Specifically, this loop: `for (const auto& pair : strVariables) { cout << ... }` Is this not what you meant to do?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted, but in the output of the code, it prints the same data twice. This is the problem.

Comment: I think I solved the problem. The problem was that I put the for loop in the wrong place.